# Using select2 in a contact form but css tricks are not working on it

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

this is the link https://dcrazed.com/html/signup-pack/ from where i took the code for animating the label the bottom line as well.
working fine on all but isn't working on multiple select.

```html
<pre>
<span class="input input--hoshi">
             <!-- <textarea style="resize:none" placeholder="" rows="5" class="input__field input__field--hoshi form-control" id="description"></textarea> -->
             <select id="services_select" class="input__field input__field--hoshi" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%" id="service">
       <option value="AL">Website Development</option>
       <option value="AL">App Development</option>
       <option value="AL">Domain Registration</option>
       <option value="AL">Hosting</option>
       <option value="AL">Plugin</option>
       <option value="AL">Logo Design</option>
       <option value="AL">Digital Marketing</option>
      </select>
             <label class="input__label input__label--hoshi input__label--hoshi-color-3" for="desc">
               <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--hoshi">services you want</span>
             </label>
           </span>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<span class="input input--hoshi">
          <select class="input__field input__field--hoshi" type="text" id="email">
    <option selected=""></option>
    <option>V2</option>
    <option>V3</option>
</select>
<label class="input__label input__label--hoshi input__label--hoshi-color-3" for="email">
     <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--hoshi">My select</span>
</label>

</span>
```

Comment: not working.. can you share running preview on a online platform??